# Proof General's cursor is covering up my code when used in the terminal

Tags: coq, proof-general

When I'm using emacs in windowed mode, everything seems fine. However, when in the terminal, Proof General's cursor (indicating where it is in the code) covers up the first two characters of the line it's on.

[image: screen shot 2015-12-08 at 4 24 00 pm]

This looks like a bug, but perhaps it's some sort of setting? Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that this is an emacs variable:

https://github.com/ProofGeneral/PG/issues/16

The overlaying of the arrow is intentional, and it can be "turned off" by setting the arrow text to `""`:

```
(setq overlay-arrow-string "")
```